# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services.gradle.org

Tags: curl, options, download, web

If in `Ubuntu Server` is executed:

```
curl https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip -O
```

appears:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services.gradle.org
```

Observe the `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: services.gradle.org` part.

If in `Fedora Server` is executed the same command, it shows:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

No error, but the `gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip` file is empty.

If you open a web browser and put the `https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip` in the address bar the download process automatically starts.

So how to fix this situation?

**Note** Just in case, both Linux are running as **VM** in `VirtualBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is some problem with your DNS resolution in the ubuntu Server

Try to set an other DNS server like `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1`

See the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and set `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

update:

After fixing the issue with DNS , add `-L` option to `curl` which allows it to "follow redirects"

The problem here was that the URL does not actually provide the file, but it redirects to another URL that actually hosts the file. This is done automatically in the browser but in `curl` the `-L` option is needed.

See the output of `wget` as example:

```
% wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
--2022-11-07 11:16:12--  https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
Resolving services.gradle.org (services.gradle.org)... 104.18.191.9, 104.18.190.9
Connecting to services.gradle.org (services.gradle.org)|104.18.191.9|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip [following]
--2022-11-07 11:16:12--  https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
Resolving downloads.gradle-dn.com (downloads.gradle-dn.com)... 104.18.164.99, 104.18.165.99
Connecting to downloads.gradle-dn.com (downloads.gradle-dn.com)|104.18.164.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 120635534 (115M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip.1’

gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip.1                             100%[================================>] 115,05M  5,31MB/s    in 21s

2022-11-07 11:16:34 (5,43 MB/s) - ‘gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip.1’ saved [120635534/120635534]
```

`301 Moved Permanently` is the redirect and after that the new URL

Comment: Can you share your `curl` execution with the same URL used? It through a Figure - I want confirm that works in your side - once confirmed that - can you share your `/etc/resolv.conf` file content? - Can you indicate why `nameserver 8.8.8.8` should be used? - Indicate your Linux distribution. Thanks

Comment: My response was related to the error "Could not resolve host: services.gradle.org" which shows a problem with DNS resolution. So my suggestion is about using a known good DNS server (like 8.8.8.8) to overcome this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - was only necessary add at the end of the command the `-L` option